# Jackson deserialization max depth level

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

With **Spring Boot** application I post JSON with **10000 nested** elements, like the one below and got `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

```
{
"__id": "1",
"__category":{
      "key1": {
        "key2": {
            "key3": {
                ...
                ...
                "key10000": "value"
                ...
                ...
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this error more manageable?

I mean, I don't want avoid this error, but do something like custom deserializer to set a value of nesting allowed and throw some exception if this value exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Jackson Streaming API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi) instead of having to deserialize the whole thing at once. That's the recommended approach when dealing with a large JSON object or array.

This allows you to deserialize and process components individually without needing the entire JSON object to exist in memory.

Comment: As I understand, the main point of my problem is a big number of recursive calls. I catch `java.lang.StackOverflowError` during recursive call of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject()` method. So if I use **Jackson Streaming API**, I will catch the same error because of very big depth of my JSON's nesting.

Comment: @Andrew With the streaming API you should be able to work with iteration instead of recursion which should substantially reduce the memory footprint. You might need a state machine if the input is fairly complex.